# need recommendatoin for handling MDM in Big Query

Tags: data-analysis, data, google

I have a large warehouse that I have multiple sources come into.  the pipelines are completely done, and the system is working.

however, quality in business fields used in Surrogate Key definitions are not held to the highest quality with respect to data importation.  I feel I need a more professional approach to my key management.  my experience indicates that I need a Master Data/Reference Data platform to manage these objects.

I need to replicate this here.  is there a master data or reference data platform that is interoperable with bigquery, and google cloud organically?

Thank you.